# No such a provider exception for BouncyCastle

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, provider

I have an application that worked perfectly up now! but now it raises `No such a provider` exception on this line of code:

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
```

BouncyCastle is installed correctly and the strange thing is only in this application it creates Exception! in others it works at the same time on the same machine with the same JRE!!!

What is the problem?

Comment: You have put all the necessary bouncy castle jars correctly in your classpath in this project?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: They are! as i said the application worked without problem until now!! and now other applications work without problem!! only this one has this problem!!

Comment: Find out what has changed since it worked the last time - it might be even something like an anti-virus update.  Also consider that You may have a corrupted jar.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Nothing on application itself!! the only change was last Ubuntu update; but I installed Java manually so system update shouldn't affect on it! should it?

Comment: Are you relying on the `java.security` file or do you explicitly add the provider within code?

Comment: Excellent question.  Try running with "java -verbose" and see if the output looks right (notably loading paths).  If you do not explicitly point to the java you want, your configuration can have changed.

Comment: 1) check the location and version of Java that is running (e.g. log it at startup). 2) make sure that the *correct signed version* of Bouncy Castle is on your classpath, and make sure the provider [is installed correctly](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: thanks for `java -verbose` from there i found the update installed OpenJDK and reconfigured `alternatives` ! changing default `java` with `update-alternatives --config java` fixed the problem.

Comment: @owlstead: yes the #1 was the problem ; thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu software update system may have changed your Java configuration.

Use the -verbose flag to see if all classes are loaded from the location you expect.